# How to modify and print a string in MIPS?

Tags: string, assembly, mips

I'm working on an assignment in MIPS. I want to print the stored string without the decimal point i.e the output should be 11011 for 110.11 .

I think my code is doing what it's supposed to, but it's not showing any output. I debugged it and it turns out that the addi statement just keeps removing the first element of the string so there's nothing left in the end.

```
.data
        string: .asciiz "110.11"
.text
.globl main
.ent main
main:
     la $t1,string
     li $t5,46              #ascii code of .=46

     LOOP:
     lb $t0,($t1)
     beq $t0,$t5,SKIP       #skip point if found
     beq $t0, $zero, exit 
     sb $t0,($t1)
     addi $t1, $t1, 1       #i++

     j LOOP

     SKIP:
     addi $t1, $t1, 1
     j LOOP

     exit:  
     li $v0,4
     move $a0,$t1
     syscall

     li $v0,10
     syscall
     jr $ra
.end main
```

Is there any way to move forward through the string without deleting its elements and getting modified string as output? Any help would be appreciated thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is obviously not doing what it's supposed to, because then you wouldn't ask the question here.

What your code basically does is

```
while (*string) {
  if (*string != '.')
    *string = *string;
  string++;
}
syscall (string);
```

So you are not only not removing the dot, but you print the empty string, or to be more precise, the terminating zero byte at the and of the string.

You say "it turns out that the `addi` statement just keeps removing the first element of the string so there's nothing left in the end". There seems to be a lack of understanding what that statement does and how it relates to zero terminated strings. The `addi` in this loop will advance the pointer till the end of the string, because that it what this loop does. Incrementing the pointer means that the pointer now points to the second byte, so you get the string starting at the next byte. The memory itself is not modified.

You can try something like this. It assumes that you configured your assembler to execute the statements in the order written, in other words reorder the statements so that the add of `t1` will go into the slot after the branch.

```
main:
     la $t1,string
     move $t2,$t1
     move $t3,$t1           # t1 = t2 = t3 = string
     li $t5,46              #ascii code of .=46

LOOP:
     lb $t0,($t1)
     addi $t1, $t1, 1       #t1++
     beq $t0,$t5,SKIP       #skip point if found
     sb $t0,($t2)
     addi $t2, $t2, 1       #t2++
SKIP:
     bneq $t0, $zero, LOOP   # exit on end of string

     li $v0,4
     move $a0,$t3
     syscall

     li $v0,10
     syscall
     jr $ra
```

In C, this would be

```
t1 = t2 = t3 = string;
do {
  t0 = *t1++;
  if (t0 != '.')
    *t2++ = t0;
} while (t0 != 0);
syscall (t3);
```

Comment: Nice well-explained answer; nice job addressing the misunderstandings of what it means to loop over the bytes of a string.  BTW, MARS and SPIM simulate a MIPS without branch delay slots (there's a menu option for that); that's why you typically see MIPS questions on SO that assume no branch-delay slots.  I assume many students aren't aware of the concept if they're just learning the basics of asm and their professor didn't burden them with that complication until they start talking about computer architecture and how pipelined CPUs work.

Comment: Thankyou so much for clearing up my misunderstanding. The code works perfectly well now!