# Print partial string in MIPS

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I would like to print out `"HEL"` from the string `"HELLO!"`. I am aware that I can load individual byte using `lb` in MIPS, however, how do I load the first 3 characters?

```
.data
    string: .asciiz "HELLO!"

.text
    lw $t6, string
    lb $a0, 0-2($t6)  # pseudo-code, returns "HEL"
    li $v0, 4 # as opposed to 11, printing character
    syscall
```

Comment: There's no system call that prints a string where the actual string contents are stored in a register. You could temporarily modify the string in the data section by storing 0 at the location of the second `'L'` and then using system call 4. Or just use three `lb` instructions and system call 11s.

Answer (score 2):

This has little to do with MIPS, and everything to do with C style nul-terminated strings, if you consider printing a character and whole string are your only options.

So, you can print the first 3 characters one a a time using syscall #11, or, copy them to another string and print it using syscall #4.

Otherwise, you can modify the string in place by smashing the 2nd L with a nul character, and print it.

Comment: How do I modify the string? I'm reading something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56584949/how-to-modify-and-print-a-string-in-mips

Comment: Ok, I figured it out using `sb`.